# How to force OnFailure in MVC AjaxRequest or otherwise parse results?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have specified a Javascript function for the "OnSuccess" event of an MVC ajax form.
However, I do not want to carry out the "OnSuccess" event depending on certain conditions such as the Modelstate being invalid. How do I intercept and and check the modelstate of the patial view OR force acomplete failure and run OnFailure event?

AND THEN, CAN I SPECIFY A DIFFERENT UpDateTarget?

Answer (score 1):

Change the HttpResponse StatusCode of your Response object

[EDIT]
To update a different target you can play with the response object in the event handlers
More explanation of the MS ajax process [here](http://msmvps.com/blogs/luisabreu/archive/2009/03/04/the-mvc-framework-a-deep-dive-on-the-client-ajax-api.aspx)